# Gmaps place marker with postal code and house number

Tags: google-maps

I use a Gmap with postal Code (PO BOX) and want to add the house number for a more perfect marker, how to add the house number? This is my code:

```
function createMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var address = '8915 CK, NL';

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});






}
```

Comment: You sure [that](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=8915%20CK,%20NL&geocode=1) is a Postal Code?

Comment: Yep! My own,and it displays the marker fine on the map...

Comment: I get two results (see the link in my original comment): Found 2 results for 8915 CK, NL: [ 0 ]: 8915 CK Leeuwarden, The Netherlands (53.2063948, 5.774195999999961), [ 1 ]: 8915 Leeuwarden, The Netherlands (53.2107808, 5.767315499999995); they just don't look like Post Codes to me; are either correct? The first does have:   "types": [ "postal_code" ]; so I guess it is the "correct" one.

Comment: If it is "your own" and it displays the marker fine on the map, what is the issue?  If you know where the place is, just use the coordinates to place the marker (don't use the geocoder if you already know the correct location).

Comment: It Marks the middle of the street,not my house.

Comment: Does the full address of your house work?  If not, then you will need to use the coordinates.

Comment: Full Adrress works, but the users on my site only fill in the Postal Code and housnumber. A Table in my database with all the streets and postal codes is verry huge! So i only want to use the postal and housenumber

Comment: Why do you think that will work? Maybe you need to request the street from your users as well.